# How do I launch Skype Call Recorder in 12.10?

Tags: skype

How can I get [Skype Call Recorder](http://atdot.ch/scr/) to work under Ubuntu 12.10?

Skype Call Recorder does not launch. I see the icon but it does not open whether Skype is on or off.

Answer (score 1):

You can install libssl.so.0.9.8 in addition to the default 1.0.0 version: [image: I am on Netrunner 12.10 hence using Muon]

Then open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `skype-call-recorder`: [image: Launch skype-call-recorder]

I have used it and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Run it in a terminal

```
skype-call-recorder
```

It shows me that Skype Call Recorder uses libssl 0.9.8 and does not seem to be upwards-compatible with the installed libssl 1.0.0 (on my 12.10 machine).

This is a problem of the provided .deb package.

You can use Skype Call recorder on 12.10 if you [compile it from source](http://atdot.ch/scr/files/0.8/skype-call-recorder-0.8.tar.gz), [using the simple manual](http://atdot.ch/scr/compiling/).